# Box - Excel Online - Sharing a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you share an Excel workbook in Excel online?

We have a file that we need multiple people to access and update, when it is opened by a user the following error message is displayed and the file is not opened:

[image: Excel-Online error message]

Answer (score 0):

"Workbook Sharing" is a feature of Office O365 that works with OneDrive and Sharepoint only. Excel Online has a different sharing feature and the two are not compatible. You can't open a "Shared Workbook" that was made in O365 in Excel Online. It's a different type of share. If you share a workbook from Excel Online it can then be edited in Excel Online, by others. Do not mix desktop and on-line versions.

For more information see this official documentation:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-and-collaborate-with-excel-online-c8ab30a3-c0fa-473e-b508-0f5186bd47a2

Answer (score 0):

Open the problem file in Desktop Excel, go to Review- Protect- select Unshare Workbook:

[image]

Resaving the file and open in Excel online again.